# JSON-schema: validating an integer formatted in a string with min and max values

Tags: jsonschema

Through a json schema validator (like `z-schema`), I would like to validate an integer formatted in a string, e.g.:

```
{
    "myvalue": "45"
}
```

Currently, the following validation schema is:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]+$"
}
```

However, now it would be great to be able to validate a minimum and maximum value, like:

```
{
    "type": "integer",
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 32
 }
```

However the above json value "45" is not an integer.

Comment: you probably send the values as string, it works I use it. I use flask-restx with validator enabled Api(...,validate=True)

Answer (score 3):

Without changing the `type` to `integer`, the best you can do is use the `pattern` keyword to enforce the range using a regular expression.  Here is an example of a regular expression to match integers from 0..32.

```
/^[1-2]?[0-9]$|^3[0-2]$/
```